# Why my event binding fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-binding

I have a link button on the .aspx page :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSynEvent" Text="Export Event to Outlook"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and a method on code behind page :

```
protected void lnkSynEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, DataTable data)
        {}
```

Now at the runtime I am trying to bind the event to the Link Button, inside a function

```
lnkSynEvent.Click +=new EventHandler((sender,args) => lnkSynEvent_Click(sender,args, eventData));
```

But when user click on the Link button it doesn't fire the Click event.
Not sure why.

Please help.

Comment: Is the `AutoPostBack` property on the button set to false?

Comment: @MAV LinkButton doesn't have an AutoPostBack I believe.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry about that. I have been playing around with postbacks all day, so it was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event back on every post back. In other words, if you attach an event inside `if (!IsPostBack)`, it wont' fire.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var data = new DataTable();
  lnkSynEvent.Click += new EventHandler((s, a) => lnkSynEvent_Click(s, a, data));
}

protected void lnkSynEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, DataTable data)
{

}
```

### The following code won't fire click event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    var data = new DataTable();
    lnkSynEvent.Click += new EventHandler((s, a) => lnkSynEvent_Click(s, a, data));
  }
}
```

Comment: thats right it registers the event binding correctly when done inside Page_Load, but the problem is I am getting this DataTable later on by a webservice and hence need to buy accordingly.Not sure if there is any way to override it, Thanks a lot for help tough.

Comment: @Vishal Sachdeva You are welcome. According to your comment, dynamic event binding might not be a good choice for your scenario due to ASP.Net page life cycle. If you create a separate question with the code, we can suggest you an alternative approach.

Comment: Win : Sure win I'll see if I am not able to find out any alternate then I'll paste it here, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an OnClick attribute to the LinkButton tag (this is setting it up at compile time).

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="lnkSynEvent_Click" ID="lnkSynEvent" Text="Export Event to Outlook"></asp:LinkButton>
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx)